# Quickblox UDP Port List

Tags: tcp, udp, port, quickblox, videochat

I am implementing video chat application using QuickBlox javascript SDK. Which are the UDP port quickblox is using for video chat?

Is it possible to set specific UDP port which quickblox can use to video chat packets?